# jQuery smooth scrolling and URL field

Tags: jquery, url, scroll, append, smooth-scrolling

I got this script...

```
$(function(){
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'#') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 1000);
            location.hash = (this.hash);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
});
```

... But I have an issue with the page jumping to top when it scrolls, but if I take out the line...

```
location.hash = (this.hash);
```

It will work fine and scrolling is all good, but the URL doesn't append to the anchor links being clicked.

Basically I need the url to show: http://www.example.com/#home <-- note the hash.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I never got it working, so went with another script.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback for `.animate`

```
$(function(){
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'#') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
            var hash = this.hash; // 'this' will not be in scope in callback
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 1000, function() {
                location.hash = hash;
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/